# React-confirm-bootstrap - Is there an 'onCancel' method?

Tags: reactjs, confirm

I am using the react-confirm-bootstrap modal to show a confirm box, but I can't handle the "*Cancel*" option. I would like to do something if the user chooses Cancel. Is there an *onCancel* method similar to *onConfirm*? Or how can I handle it?

var Confirm = require('react-confirm-bootstrap');

```
var ConfirmAction = React.createClass({
    onConfirm() {
        // Preform your action.
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <Confirm
                onConfirm={this.onConfirm}
                body="Are you sure you want to delete this?"
                confirmText="Confirm Delete"
                title="Deleting Stuff">
                <button>Delete Stuff</button>
            </Confirm>
        )
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

onClose: React.PropTypes.func

Function to be called once closed.

```
var ConfirmAction = React.createClass({
    onConfirm() {
       // Preform your action.
    },
    afterClose() {
      // you code after close
    },


    render() {
        return (
            <Confirm
                onConfirm={this.onConfirm}
                body="Are you sure you want to delete this?"
                confirmText="Confirm Delete"
                title="Deleting Stuff">
                onClose={this.afterClose}
                <button>Delete Stuff</button>
            </Confirm>
        )
    },
});
```